# Flutter i keep getting Bad State: No element. when im trying to get my userId from previous screen

Tags: flutter, provider

i keep getting error when im trying to get a data from previous layout and use it on my provider

this is my seller_profile_screen.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../models & providers/seller.dart';

class SellerProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/seller-profile-screen';

  const SellerProfileScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SellerProfileScreen> createState() => _SellerProfileScreenState();
}

class _SellerProfileScreenState extends State<SellerProfileScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    final sellerProvider = Provider.of<SellerProvider>(context);
    final seller = sellerProvider.getById(userId);

    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

this is my seller provider file

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Seller with ChangeNotifier {
  final double joinedDate;
  final String id;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String city;
  final String name;

  Seller({
    required this.joinedDate,
    required this.id,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.city,
    required this.name,
  });
}

class SellerProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Seller> _sellers = [];

  Future<void> fetchProducts() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot sellerSnapshot) {
      _sellers = [];
      for (var element in sellerSnapshot.docs) {
        _sellers.insert(
          0,
          Seller(
            joinedDate: double.parse(element.get('joinedDate')),
            id: element.get('id'),
            imageUrl: element.get('imageUrl'),
            city: element.get('location'),
            name: element.get('name'),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
  }

  List<Seller> sellers() => _sellers;

  Seller getById(String userId) {
    return _sellers.firstWhere((element) => element.id == userId);
  }

  List<Seller> getBySearch(String search) {
    List<Seller> sellList = _sellers
        .where((element) =>
            element.name.toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
    return sellList;
  }
}
```

and this is what i did when i want to get my data in my previous file

```
onTap: () {
     Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
     SellerProfileScreen.routeName,
     arguments: widget.product.userId);
},
```

that was in my gesturedetector

but when i remove or put double slash on my `final seller = sellerProvider.getById(userId);` error gone but i cant get my data from it

this is what is the debug console say

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Bad state: No element
The relevant error-causing widget was
SellerProfileScreen
lib\main.dart:87
```

and i already pretty sure that i get my id from previous layout but this code keep give me a bad state L no element

`final seller = sellerProvider.getById(userId);`

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Update the post with the error message.

Comment: @BrunoJ. updated already

Comment: try adding **var** in front of the seller variable it should fix it for you and also add **var** to the other variables as well

Comment: @PandaCórdoba infront of my seller? so i put them into 'var seller = sellerProvider.getById(userId)' ?? i tried and still error

Comment: ```final sellerProvider = Provider.of<SellerProvider>(context, listen:false).getById(userId); ``` try this

Comment: @PandaCórdoba still on `Bad state : no element`

Comment: I'm referencing from this github repo https://github.com/NiiTyy/UserManager-FlutterApp/blob/main/user_flutter_app/lib/src/screens/user_detail_screen.dart

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that your code (the `firstWhere` function) cannot find any Sellers with the provided ID. Double-check that such a seller exists in Firebase. I would also recommend handling this in cases where it could happen in your app.

There are also some methods that could help you out, like `firstWhereOrNull` instead of `firstWhere`

Comment: well i tried print the id from previous layout to check is there the id was exist and yes it is. but when i tried to send it to next layout the error showed up

Comment: Not sure, but that's why the error is ocurring.